# Trying to translate Unix Python date "dates['mm'] = date.strftime('%m')" to it's Windows equivalent

Tags: python, linux, windows

Moved Some code over from Linux to Windows to test.

I have this line in my program

```
mm = hadoop.date_part()['mm']
```

The relevant section of the hadoop.date_part class is the follwoing.

```
dates = dict()
if date == None:
    date = datetime.now()
else:
    date = datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y')

dates['mm'] = date.strftime('%m')
dates['m'] = date.strftime('%-m')
dates['mmm'] = date.strftime('%b')
dates['mmmm'] = date.strftime('%B')
dates['yy'] = date.strftime('%y')
dates['yyyy'] = date.strftime('%Y')
dates['d'] = date.strftime('%-d')
dates['dd'] = date.strftime('%d')
return dates
```

When I run the program above I get the following error:

```
dates['m'] = date.strftime('%-m')
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

I understand it could be the fact that date formatting is different in Linux than it is in Windows.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The format

```
dates['m'] = date.strftime('%-m')   # Linux
```

indeed works in Linux, but not in Windows. What you can do in Windows is use the number sign instead:

```
dates['m'] = date.strftime('%#m')   # Windows
```

The disadvantage is that you need different codes for the two platforms. To keep the same code you can do some formatting after `strfime`, like

```
import re

dates['m'] = re.sub('^0', '', date.strftime('m'))
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you!

Comment: Your are welcome. If this answer has solved your question. Please can you tick "Accept this answer". Thanks!